# Git Flow - Synchronizing two Unfinished Features

Tags: git, git-flow

We are working on one of our academic projects. Recently discovered Git Flow and are quite excited about it. But I have an issue which I would be glad if could be clarified.

Our group, divided into two sub-groups, works on multiple features. We just discovered that we need one unfinished feature to be used in another feature. That sure sounds crazy but this is the reason. I believe that we should have made features more atomic, but the division was made on entire namespaces. Then I went on coding frenzy and with some luck in simplifying the issue turbo boosted our side of project finishing our feature way ahead the schedule. The only feature left to work on for this semester depends on team B's product.

Just to be clear:

- Team A - Feature X, Feature Z (requires some of Feature Y)
- Team B - Feature Y
- Team A is starting Feature Z, Team B hasn't finished feature Y.

Can Team A kind of checkout the code by Team B's Feature Y to continue with the project? Team B will update Feature Y in time, and Team A be able to fetch the updates as necessary.

Our current plan is to finish the current feature half way, factor the remainder work in to more atomic features and work on them. Then we (Team A) are hoping to `rebase` and keep ourselves up to date.

Any suggestion, apart from being a direct answer, would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can Team A kind of checkout the code by Team B's Feature `Y`

If Team B releases an intermediate version of `Y`, then team A can track `Y` from its own repo.
See this [answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710947/6309):

```
git flow feature track my-feature-branch
```

(based on [`git flow CLI`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments), and [`git flow track`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L347-L365))

Once you are tracking Y on team A's own repo, A can merge or rebase its work on top of `Y`.

Comment: Checked it out a little, seems to be what I want... Thanks a lot for the help! If I have any question I will put down a comment.